# Make overlapping histogram in with geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make an overlapping histogram like this:

[image: Desired histogram]

```
ggplot(histogram, aes = (x), mapping = aes(x = value)) + 
    geom_histogram(data = melt(tpm_18_L_SD), breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1),
                   aes(y = 100*(..count../sum(..count..))), alpha=0.2) + 
    geom_histogram(data = melt(tpm_18_S_SD), breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1),
                   aes(y = 100*(..count../sum(..count..))), alpha=0.2) + 
    geom_histogram(data = melt(tpm_18_N_SD), breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1),
                   aes(y = 100*(..count../sum(..count..))), alpha=0.2) + 
    facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x') + 
    ylim(0, 20) +
    ylab("Percentage of Genes") +
    xlab("Standard Deviation")
```

My code can only make them plot side by side and I would like to also make them overlap. Thank you! I based mine off of the original post where this came from but it did not work for me. It was originally 3 separate graphs which I combined with grid and ggarrange. It looks like this right now.

Here is the code of the three separate graphs.

```
SD_18_L <- ggplot(data = melt(tpm_18_L_SD), mapping = aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count../sum(..count..))), breaks = seq(1, 10, by = 1)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x') + 
  ylim(0, 20) +
  ylab("Percentage of Genes") +
  xlab("Standard Deviation")

SD_18_S <- ggplot(data = melt(tpm_18_S_SD), mapping = aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count../sum(..count..))), breaks = seq(1, 10, by = 1)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x') + 
  ylim(0, 20) +
  ylab("Percentage of Genes") +
  xlab("Standard Deviation")

SD_18_N <- ggplot(data = melt(tpm_18_N_SD), mapping = aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count../sum(..count..))), breaks = seq(1, 10, by = 1)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x') + 
  ylim(0, 20) +
  ylab("Percentage of Genes") +
  xlab("Standard Deviation")
```

What my graphs look like now:
[image: What my graphs look like now]

Comment: This could help http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot` expects dataframes in a long format. I'm not sure what your data looks like, but you shouldn't have to call `geom_histogram` for each category. Instead, get all your data into a single dataframe (you can use `rbind` for this) in long format (what you're doing already with `melt`) first, then feed it into `ggplot` and map fill to whatever your categorical variable is.

Your call to `facet_wrap` is what puts them in 3 different plots. If you want them all on the same plot, take that line out.

An example using the iris data:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.6, position = "identity")
```

I decreased alpha in `geom_histogram` so you can see where colors overlap, and added `position = "identity"` so observations aren't being stacked. Hope that helps!